# Is there a media player that can be told to a)ignore rotational metadata b)pay attention to rotational metadata?

Tags: video

Is there a media player that can be told to a)ignore rotational metadata b)pay attention to rotational metadata?

For example,  suppose I have a file blah.mp4 http://ge.tt/5gTCUm13 (a small video file, 2.3MB)

It has no rotational metadata. `ffmpeg -i blah.mp4 2>&1 | find "rotat"` returns nothing.

I create a blah2.mp4 `ffmpeg -i blah.mp4 -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90 -c copy blah2.mp4` So, instructing any player to rotate the video 90 degrees anti-clockwise.

Windows Media Player, ignores rotational metadata, and displays the video blah2.mp4 oriented the same as blah.mp4

VLC, follows the metadata, and rotates the video 90 degrees anti-clockwise.

Both are useful features to me.. As I may want to see what the video looks like when not following rotational metadata, or when following rotational metadata.  I can use WMP when I want metadata ignored, and VLC when I want metadata followed.

But is there a video playing program that has an option so that it can be set to either i.e. xor a) ignore rotational metadata (i.e. just as windows media player does)  , or b) follow rotational metadata ?

related- https://superuser.com/questions/1579887/does-wmp-or-vlc-have-a-way-to-choose-whether-or-not-to-obey-rotational-metadata or https://web.archive.org/web/20200822183413/https://superuser.com/questions/1579887/does-wmp-or-vlc-have-a-way-to-choose-whether-or-not-to-obey-rotational-metadata

Answer (score 1):

ffplay can

https://ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html

```
-autorotate
Automatically rotate the video according to file metadata. 
Enabled by default, use -noautorotate to disable it.
```

The options  ,actually two, -autorotate and -noautorotate, take no parameters, and are about whether or not to obey rotational metadata.

So e.g. `ffplay blah.mp4 -noautorotate` or `ffplay blah.mp4 -autorotate` (default)